# FFMPEG recording in ASP.NET Core mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, ffmpeg, video-streaming, recording

I'm using ASP.NET Core and ffmpeg to record a live video stream. When the page receives a get request, the stream should begin recording and saving to a folder using ffmpeg. I want to make it so that when visiting the *stop* endpoint, the ffmpeg process is closed cleanly.

Unfortunately I'm unable to send a 'q' to stdin after leaving the Get method. Using taskkill requires the use of /F making the ffmpeg process (which is not a window) force quit and not save the video properly, resulting in a corrupt file.

I tried using `Process.Kill()` but that results in a corrupt file as well. Also, I tried `Process.CloseMainWindow()` which worked, but only when the process is started as a window, and I'm unable to start the process as a window in the server I'm using.

I've include the code I have so far below, so hopefully someone could lead me in the right path.

```cs
using System;
...
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class RecordingController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public RecordingController(ApplicationDbContext context, ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
        {

            // Define the os process
            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                // ffmpeg arguments
                Arguments = "-f mjpeg -i \"https://urlofstream.com/video.gci\" -r 5 \"wwwroot/video.mp4\"",
                FileName = "ffmpeg.exe",
                UseShellExecute = true
            };

            var p1 = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

            // p1.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync("q"); <-- This works here but not in the Stop method

            return Ok(p1.Id);
        }


        // GET: api/Recording/stop
        [HttpGet("stop/{pid}")]
        public ActionResult Stop(int pid)
        {
            Process processes = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
            processes.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync("q");     // Does not work, is not able to redirect input
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered a solution to this issue which could hopefully help others. The solution is to use a combination of a Singleton, with a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) and write to the StandardInput. The only way you can write to standard input of a running process is if you still have access to the started Process handle, and you wont have access to it from within the controller, so you'll need to create a singleton and store the processes in a ConcurrentDictionary (which is great for updated from multiple threads).

First I created a recording manager class. **RecordingManager.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyApp.Services
{
    public class RecordingManager
    {
        // Key int is the ProcessId. Value process is the running Process
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, Process> _processes = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Process>();

        public Process Start()
        {
            // Define the os process
            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                // ffmpeg arguments
                Arguments = "-f mjpeg -i https://urlofstream.com/video.gci -r 5 wwwroot/video.mp4",
                FileName = "ffmpeg.exe",
                RedirectStandardInput = true, // Must be set to true
                UseShellExecute = false       // Must be set to false
            };

            Process p = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

            // Add the Process to the Dictionary with Key: Process ID and value as the running process
            _processes.TryAdd(p1.Id, p);

            return p;
        }

        private Process GetProcessByPid(int pid)
        {
            return _processes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == pid).Value;
        }

        public void Stop(int pid)
        {
            Process p = GetProcessByPid(pid);

            // FFMPEG Expects a q written to the STDIN to stop the process
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("q\n");
            _processes.TryRemove(pid, out p);

            // Free up resources
            p.Close()
        }
    }
}
```

Next I add the singleton to my **startup.cs** class within the ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddSingleton<RecordingManager>();
```

Finally, I add the singleton to my controller constructor and call the methods there. **RecordingController.cs**

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class RecordingController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly RecordingManager _recordingManager;

        public RecordingController(ApplicationDbContext context, ILogger<HomeController> logger, RecordingManager recordingManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
            _recordingManager = recordingManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
        {
            Process p = _recordingManager.Start();
            return Ok(p.Id); // Wouldn't recommend simply returning an Ok Result here. Check for issues
        }


        // GET: api/Recording/stop
        [HttpGet("stop/{pid}")]
        public ActionResult Stop(int pid)
        {
            _recordingManager.Stop(pid);
            return Ok(); // Wouldn't recommend simply returning an Ok Result here. Check for issues
        }
    }
}
```